# Javascript/React-Native User input - error fixing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, error-handling

I'm a new developer and I'm wondering if there is a way to "transform" the data a user enters on your app.

I'm building an app that takes a "Start date YYYY/MM/DD" and an "End date YYYY/MM/DD".

The app would then return an array of info based on the given date range.
The issue is that, apart from adding the "YYYY/MM/DD" date format to my placeholder I can't do much more to ensure that the user will enter a date range that matches the date range style my API accepts.
Is there a "Javascript" way to handle issues around date format that would "fix" possible user mistakes?(I'm using react native to build my app)
I'm not looking for a way to handle errors, I'm looking for a way to return data even if the user enters a format that is different from the given format YYYY/MM/DD.
[image: APP user input]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Cheers!

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-date-picker
to pick date, and the use `moment` to formate it. I suggest don't allow user to enter the date, allow them to pick the date from date picker.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I can't add a date picker to the design, it has to allow the user to "write" the date.

Comment: In this case you can intercept the input in your `onChangeText`, count the number of characters if it is 4 then append one slash(/) behind and then likewise for further inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for your reference :

Put some more validations in `handleInput` as per your requirement.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  const [ date, setDate] = useState(null);


  const handleInput = (text) => {

    //Put some validation for number's checking

    if(text.length == 4 || text.length == 7)
    {
      text = text+'/';
    }

    if(text.length > 10)
    {
      alert("not a valid date");
    }

    setDate(text);

  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput 
         value={date}
         style={{backgroundColor:'red', height: 50}}
         placeholder={"YYYY/MM/YY"}
         onChangeText={handleInput}
      />
    </View> 
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. This is not exactly what I was looking for but it gives me a different alternative. cheers!